# Filtering sum of specific value

Tags: tableau-api

I have data source with different steps in a flow for different dates, and their counts let's say:

```
1 xxx 500
2 yyy 200
3 ddd 100
NA test 50
NA test2 600
NA test3 400
```

I'd like to visualize counts, but if the value is NA to filter based on amount. I already tried this

> IF [step_number] == "NA" THEN [step_count] END

But dragging this to filter actually filters everything. My goal is to only filter if the step_number is "NA". Any advice?

To clarify, filtering by 500 with this calculated field would show step_numbers 1,2,3 and NA-test2

Comment: what is the output you want? Can you post it in formatted manner.

Comment: hi, I actually found satisfying solution for now at least:

calculated metric > IF [step_number] == "NA" THEN [step_count] ELSE NULL END

I pull this to filter and can make it filter with slider only based on count of "NA"-titled fields

Answer (score 0):

if you want to only filter NA just click on keep only on NA

[image]

Your filter 'NA' data

[image]